# How to carry the php post data from one page to another?

Tags: php

I have three pages and I would like to have the process be in this order..

1) User types in email in a form and hits enter

2) There is a middle page that keeps the same email post data from user and sends the user to mailing list (same domain as in step 1) I'm sure I'll use a php header.

3) The mailing list receives the email  (different domain)

I really do not have any clue on how to start this. Is there a better way? I just need that middle page to be there...

Thank you.

Comment: i only see the need for the data on page 2, which you are posting the form to (1 and 2 could be the same page as well); as page 3 is another domain, sessions wont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

> Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data
>   across subsequent accesses.

Your middle page would look like this:

```
$_SESSION['myvar'] = $_POST['myvar'];
```

Now, `$_SESSION['myvar']` can be referenced on any page where `session_start();` is placed.